# Open Ms Word document inside iPad Application

Tags: ipad, ios4, ms-word

I need to open Ms Word document inside my iPad application. Actually I need a Ms Word viewer control on my iPad application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://libopc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

one problem I ran into is that the library is armv6, and that is being deprecated.  I've had a hard time locating a MS Office-sdk for iphone.  I wanted to try and render a word document in a container other than UIWebView or QuickLookPreview.  I have found that while some documents render just fine, there are word documents that don't render correctly, where the right most margin is sliced off, and if the document has useful info on the right side of the document, then it becomes useless to the end user.