# How can we programmatically edit an external document (such as doc ppt and pdf) in iPad app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, document

I am working on a project where I need to edit external document such as doc, ppt and PDF and re save it with same name and location. I also want to search some text in that document and mark it with different color.

Please advice with some solutions.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For each type of document you want to support you need to include some kind of support. Want to edit DOC files? Then you need to write code that can open a DOC file, show it in the right format, understand how you edit the file and last but not least, save it back in the right format.

Same for PPT en PDF file formats.

Here is a topic with the same question:
[Open Ms Word document inside iPad Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802231/open-ms-word-document-inside-ipad-application)

They answered with a link to a library which might be able to open DOC files, but as other answers mention, it is ARMv6 only (maybe updated now).